# UITesting with xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

I am setting up some ui tests with the new ui testing feature of xcode7 but am having a little difficulty figuring out how to set a textfield value to "" without pushing the delete button a whole bunch of times. 
How can I do this

**my testing code:**

```
func testLogin(){

        let app = XCUIApplication()
        let requiredTextField = app.textFields["required"]

        requiredTextField.tap()


        //here is where i want to set it to ""
        requiredTextField.typeText("username1")
        app.typeText("\r")
        ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first do a double tap that will highlight the whole textfield, then directly input your new text.

```
requiredTextField.doubleTap()
requiredTextField.typeText("yourNewText")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

```
requiredTextField.pressForDuration:0.5()
app.menuItems[@"Select All"].tap()
app.menuItems[@"Cut"].tap()
```